# Techniques to have absolute positioning while keeping elements within normal document flow?

Tags: css

We have a responsive layout where some content has a max-width (for line-length readability) and elements such as images, sliders and galleries need to break out and become full width like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rruxf/9/

Obviously `position:absolute;` achieves this but removes the item from normal document flow which doesn't work.

Our workaround is to have separate .page divs after each .full div but this is quickly becoming painful for the client.

The answers we've found either don't apply to this specific use case or are restricted by browser version.

This site is IE9+ so we were wondering if there's anything new (flexbox etc) that might achieve this type of layout?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you need to make anything absolute positioned. Could you not just set alternating divs:

```
<div class="page">
   ...text content ....
</div>
<div class="full">
   ...image ....
</div>
<div class="page">
   ...text content ....
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could set the max-width on the p tag.

```
.page p {max-width: 600px;}
```

I would probably be inclined to do something like this if you need the .page div for something generic:

```
<style>
    .page {width: 100%;}
    .text-column {max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;}
</style>

<div class="page">
    <div class="text-column"><p>...text content...</p></div>
    <img src="url">
    <div class="text-column"><p>...text content...</p></div>
</div><!-- end of page -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We're currently doing your first option as a workaround but it means locking-in which items are full-width and which are not - this is quickly becoming frustrating when entering content via a cms across different pages. The second option is better but it still requires adding divs to all the content instead of just the exceptions (images etc). No worries if this isn't possible, we just thought we'd check as it would save a lot of aggravation. Cheers